# axet/desktop: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/Platform

Tags: java, maven, noclassdeffounderror

I'm build project from repository https://github.com/axet/desktop/tree/master/java. And i'm trying to run DesktopTest class. I do that:

```
$ mvn package
$ cd target
$ java -cp ./desktop-2.3.3.jar:.:test-classes/ com.github.axet.desktop.DesktopTest
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/Platform
        at com.github.axet.desktop.Desktop.getDesktopFolders(Desktop.java:53)
        at com.github.axet.desktop.Desktop.getHomeFolder(Desktop.java:32)
        at com.github.axet.desktop.DesktopTest.main(DesktopTest.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jna.Platform
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

What i doing wrong?

Java version:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

Comment: The problem is that you are explicitly specifying the classpath and excluding the location of all the dependencies that maven included.  (Once you solve the JNA jar problem manually you'll end up with another NoClassDefFoundError until you get all of them.)    Maven manages all these dependencies for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not downloaded the dependencies for the package.  They are listed in the `pom.xml` file.  But you should not have to worry about doing that manually.

Instead of simply using `mvn package` you should execute:

```
$ mvn clean dependency:copy-dependencies package
```

That will copy all the needed jars into the `target/dependency` directory.  Add that directory to your classpath and it should work, e.g.,

```
$ java -cp ./desktop-2.3.3.jar:.:test-classes/:dependency/* com.github.axet.desktop.DesktopTest
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Please comment so I can improve my answer.  (Unless you're the previous answerer downvoting in revenge.)